# Wo soll er denn hin?

Tags: verb

In the sentence

> Wo soll er denn hin?

what is the main verb? "*Soll*" is an auxiliary verb and "*hin*" is the verb meaning "*go*" in English. (My book explains it that "*hin*" is an adverb here which seems wrong.)

Of course in "Wo gehst du hin?", "hin" is an adverb.
Isn't my understanding correct? I need to confirm.

Comment: Unfortunately your book is right and you are wrong. *Hin* is always an adverb. One could rephrase the sentcence to *Wo soll er hingehen?*, but any similiarity of *hin* and *go* ends here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

German has [separable verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_verb), and [hinsollen](http://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/hinsollen.htm) is such a verb. (You can also find it in [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hinsollen).)

In the sentence

> Wo soll er denn hin?

The words »soll« and »hin« are both parts of the main verb. »Soll« is never an auxiliary verb. German has only three verbs that can be used as auxiliary verbs:

> *Haben*, *sein* und *werden*
>   sind die drei Hilfszeitwörter auf Erden

*Sollen* ist not one of those three verbs.

The word-by word translation of this sentence is:

> Where to-must he?

English has no separable verbs, and »hinsollen« has no 1:1 translation in English.

Also [reinmüssen](http://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/reinmu:ssen.htm) is a separable verb, it works exactly the same way as *hinsollen*

btw:

In German the verbs *müssen* and *sollen* also can be used to describe a movement, see https://german.stackexchange.com/a/22628/1487

Comment: Wow, there are numerous separable verbs in German. Thanks!

Comment: I would call *sollen* an auxiliary in a sentence like ‘Ich soll gehen.’ But maybe it’s closer to a modal verb.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to analyse an English translation of that sentence. Yes,

> Wo soll er (denn) hin?

should be translated *Where should he go?* (This *denn* is a particle which has no matching English equivalent; to translate it you need more context.)

But, **literally**, the German sentence had to be translated *Where should he **to**?*

Of course, that isn't proper English. English requires the *go*. But it's proper German without it. *Sollen* isn't a auxiliary in that sentence but a full verb, meaning *should go*. Same with **müssen**, and **können**.

> Wo soll ich nur hin?
>
> Wo muss noch Salz rein?
>
> Wo kann noch etwas drauf?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. it helps but I selected the other answer which explained it clearer to me about the word 'hinsollen'.

Comment: It's okay. Just be careful this is only one of a family of words starting with an adverb of direction as the prefix and *sollen*, *müssen*, *können* as the base verb.

Comment: Yes, hinkönnen, hinmüssen are good words I learned from your post.