# What's the verb in the sentence "Ich muss wieder zum Zahnarzt."?

Tags: modal-verb

It's a sentence I found in a German children's book. The translation of the sentence "Ich muss wieder zum Zahnarzt." is "I must return to the dentist.", right? So, "muss" is a modal verb. Is the main verb, e.g. "gehen" missing?

Comment: Yes, the main verb "gehen" is implied. I'd translate it as "go again", not "return". But you got the meaning correct.

Comment: Being a dentist myself, I like this question. <g>

Comment: Also related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35232/wo-soll-er-denn-hin/35234#35234

Answer (score 2):

The only literal verb in this sentence is "muss" meaning must/have to so you are right there. And as you have said, the verb "gehen" is missing, but it is optional whether to omit it or not here.

"Gehen" is there in spirit.

Answer (score 2):

Allgemein gesagt können deutsche Modalverben mit Ortsergänzung oft auch ohne Bewegungsverb konstruiert werden. Die Ortsergänzung kann auch ein adverbiales Verbpräfix sein:

> willst du schon los? (= wegfahren, weggehen, aufbrechen)
>
> ich will nach Hause, lass uns fahren
>
> er muss weg (= uns verlassen), wir müssen uns etwas beeilen
>
> die Kinder dürfen / können heute früher nach Hause, der Sportlehrer ist krank
>
> ich soll ins Krankenhaus, und anschließend noch 3 Wochen in die Reha

Ähnlich:

> möchtest du noch einen Kaffee? (= trinken)

Umgangssprachlich sind Bewegungsverben oft weglassbar:

> Dann kam die Polizei. Er sofort runter und sich mit den Beamten angelegt.
>
> Heute sollte es 250-Euro-Notebooks bei Mediamarkt geben. Ich sofort da hin, aber alles war schon weg.